# Как очистить консоль C#?

Tags: c#, консоль

Каким образом возможно очистить консоль в C#?

Comment: Наберите Console, поставьте точку, Visual Studio выдаст список доступных методов, просто просмотрите его. Так можно решить 90% вопросов подобных этому.

Comment: А за что минусы? Нормальный новичковый вопрос.

Comment: @VladD подозреваю, что минус за нежелание ткнуть кнопочку F1 или просто зайти на страницу описания используемого класса. Плюс конечно тоже ставить не за что, но беда в том, что в MSDN далеко не все описано правильно, и еще меньше правильно переведено на русский, автоперевод, чтоб его, лучше бы, как раньше, студенты переводили, хоть с ошибками, зато по смыслу процентов на 70 верно, в большинстве случаев.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ок, попробую

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не знаю насколько канонично получилось, но вобщем вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656243/198316

Comment: @rdorn Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Следует использовать:

```
Console.Clear();
```