# Как пользоваться справкой VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, faq

Существует много простых вопросов, на которые можно ответить ссылкой или примером кода взятыми из официальной документации Microsoft. Судя по тому, что количество таких вопросов неуклонно растет, не все знают о существовании встроенной в студию справочной системы, а если и знают, то не умеют быстро и удобно ей пользоваться.

Здесь постараемся раскрыть тонкости использования справочной системы студии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Т.к. читать сегодня тоже не очень модно, начну с главного, как быстро получить интересующую информацию.

В десктопных приложениях, исторически сложилось, что клавиша **F1** служит для вызова справки. VisualStudio также использует эту клавишу для работы со справкой, но в более широком смысле. Если вас интересует справка по какому то классу, методу и или функции поставляемым в библиотеках Microsoft, достаточно поставить текстовый курсор (выделять полностью не обязательно) в редакторе кода на имя интересующего элемента  и нажать **F1**. VisualStudio автоматически создаст поисковый запрос к справочной системе и откроет соответствующий раздел справки, если такой имеется в наличии.

Microsoft предоставляет два варианта справки доступной напрямую из IDE: [online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa187916.aspx) и [offline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh580782.aspx). В настоящее время, визуальное представление Online и Offline версий практически не отличается. Слева навигация по дереву разделов документации, справа - навигация по разделам статьи.

**Качество документации:**

Сначала о хорошем:

- в той или иной степени документировано все.
- много рабочих примеров кода, некоторые из которых довольно часто используются практически без изменений и дополнений в рабочих проектах.
- есть пошаговые инструкции для выполнения типовых задач, таких как, например, чтение и запись файлов, создание простых оконных приложений, создание простых сервисов и т.д.

Ну и о плохом:

- если есть возможность, то лучше читать документацию на оригинальном английском, т.к. с некоторых пор MSDN использует систему автоматического перевода для локализации, что негативно сказывается на качестве локализованных текстов.
- присутствуют некоторые неточности и неоднозначности в оригинальной версии.
- отдельные разделы документированы весьма условно (камень в огород WinAPI и еще некоторых).

Но не смотря на все недостатки не очень хорошая документация однозначно лучше чем ее полное отсутствие.

Offline вариант можно установить вместе с VisualStudio или добавить позже. Важная особенность Offline-справки - ее можно загружать частями, по мере необходимости. [Установка локального содержимого и управление им](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh580802.aspx). Сразу хочу предупредить, что полный объем справочной информации превышает несколько десятков гигабайт и это только для .NET, так что это не быстрый процесс, но в результате вы сможете искать информацию независимо от наличия выхода в сеть.

Comment: Касаемо документации по .NET Framework: Майкрософт вместе с релизом .NET Framework 4.7 недавно представила новую, более удобную систему документации с мгновенным поиском. Обещают, что в течение этого года она полностью заменит привычную msdn. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.6.2

Comment: @Nikita шкурка не главное, это удел маркетологов. Главное содержание, а я что-то сомневаюсь что они откажутся от автоперевода, и существенно улучшат описание существующих классов, скорее просто перенесут статьи на новый движок, на чем все и закончится. Но за ссылку спасибо, попробовал, действительно быстрее текущего

Comment: @Nikita посмотрел на новую шкурку внимательнее. Честно говоря остался в смешанных чувствах, с одной стороны скорость реакции потрясающая, с другой мелкие баги (ладно, к релизу думаю поправят) и неудачное во многих аспектах отображение контента. Сами материалы полностью совпадают с оригинальной MSDN, плюс добавлен список наследников классов и интерфейсов, иногда бывает нужно, но представление списка ужасное. Тоже касается списка унаследованных членов класса - голый список ссылок, в котором банально определить наличие проблема, сравните с табличками в оригинальной MSDN