# Проверка существования значения в БД MS SQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, поиск

Есть БД MS SQL, в ней есть записи содержащие информацию о человеке (ФИО, возраст, город). Хочу сделать чтобы при добавлении новой записи была выполнена проверка что такой записи не существует в данной БД. Видел что это можно сделать с помощью запроса SELECT FROM. Ниже приведен код с запросом. Использую C#.

```
SqlCommand equal = connect.CreateCommand();
equal.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE ФИО = 'Иванов Иван Иванович'";
```

Правильно ли написан запрос? Какой ответ я должен получить если такой человек есть и что, если нет? Как получить ответ на данный запрос?
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Запрос верный. Но бессмысленный. Ну есть - что дальше? Или нет - что дальше? лучше почитайте справку по MERGE.

Comment: @Akina, Вы могли подробней написать как получить ответ на данный запрос? И как ответ должен выглядеть?

Comment: Такое лучше реализовать с помощью атрибута `Unique` на столбец ФИО

Comment: @Bulson Полные тезки встречаются чаще, чем может показаться.

Comment: по классу SqlCommand и сопутствующим, есть подробная справка с действующими примерами кода. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656244/198316

Comment: По поводу уникальности имён имею своё мнение... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы конечно на уровне БД это делал с оформлением в виде процедур, но если так хочется в коде это сделать, то самый простой вариант будет:

```
if not exists(select 1 from People_list WHERE ФИО = 'Иванов Иван Иванович')
    insert into...
```